# Get the Real-time lpr result from hikvision camera

Tags: postman

I want to get the real-time LPR Result from a Hikvision LPR Camera. I have the link from Hikvision ISAPI Document: /ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/plates

I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResponseStatus version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.std-cgi.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
    <requestURL>/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/plates</requestURL>
    <statusCode>6</statusCode>
    <statusString>Invalid XML Content</statusString>
    <subStatusCode>badXmlContent</subStatusCode>
</ResponseStatus>
```

This link does not work whereas the link /ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/ works. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Invalid XML Content

HTTP Content "0" < grab the last20 plates

HTTP Methods IS "POST" !!! not GET the documentation is wrong, A get never send any data to the serveur ;), this is why you get an invalid xml format at input

Comment: AfterTime  picTime 0 /picTime  /AfterTime < just add the < and > ^^

Answer (score 1):

Works:

```
$username = 'xxxxx';
$password = 'yyyyy';

$url = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/plates";



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<AfterTime version=\"2.0\"><picTime>2020-06-20T00:00:00Z</picTime></AfterTime>"); 
$first_response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

preg_match('/WWW-Authenticate: Digest (.*)/', $first_response, $matches);

if(!empty($matches))
{
  $auth_header = $matches[1];
  $auth_header_array = explode(',', $auth_header);
  $parsed = array();

  foreach ($auth_header_array as $pair)
  {
    $vals = explode('=', $pair);
    $parsed[trim($vals[0])] = trim($vals[1], '" ');
  }

  $response_realm     = (isset($parsed['realm'])) ? $parsed['realm'] : "";
  $response_nonce     = (isset($parsed['nonce'])) ? $parsed['nonce'] : "";
  $response_opaque    = (isset($parsed['opaque'])) ? $parsed['opaque'] : "";

  $authenticate1 = md5($username.":".$response_realm.":".$password);
  $authenticate2 = md5("POST:".$url);

  $authenticate_response = md5($authenticate1.":".$response_nonce.":".$authenticate2);

  $request = sprintf('Authorization: Digest username="%s", realm="%s", nonce="%s", opaque="%s", uri="%s", response="%s"',
  $username, $response_realm, $response_nonce, $response_opaque, $url, $authenticate_response);

  $request_header = array($request);
  $request_header[] = 'Content-Type:application/json';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<AfterTime version=\"2.0\"><picTime>2020-06-20T00:00:00Z</picTime></AfterTime>"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_header);

  $result['response']= curl_exec($ch);
  
 print_r($result['response']);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem when I ommited to post the input parameter, this following CURL command returns `badXmlContent`:

```
curl --digest --user xxx:xxx  
      http://172.27.111.50/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/plates
```

But this one works ok:

```
curl --digest --user xxx:xxx  
     http://172.27.111.50/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/vehicleDetect/plates 
     -d "<AfterTime><picTime>2022-03-10T14:00:00Z</picTime></AfterTime>"
```

So the problem was omitting

```
-d "<AfterTime><picTime>2022-03-10T14:00:00Z</picTime></AfterTime>"
```